# Removing area name from route in MVC 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, captcha

I am using SimpleMvcCaptcha. My enviroment has different areas. I want to use this captcha in different forms on differet areas.

This module needs a controller with the name of say Captcha and one method in it. 
If I create this controller in the same area that I am using it, then there is no problem, but if I use it in different areas, I am getting this error:

```
 The controller for path '/AreaName/Captcha/GetImage/15fe4de1-fd46-4f2f-a0d1-74c397bd8365' could not be found.
```

How can I solve this problem? One way that I think I can solve this problem is to remove the area in route registration such as

```
  routes.MapRoute(
           "Default_Captcha",
            "AreaName/Captcha/{action}/{id}",
            new { area = string.Empty, controller = "Captcha", action = "GetImage", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

But I am still getting the same error.

Is there any way that I can remove area name from the link?

**--- Update**

The Captcha needs a controller for its operation (The controller with one method for getting captcha image).

I want to use it in a form which is implemented in MyArea. The form relates to a controller called MyController.

If I create a CaptchaController in this area with the required code inside it, the captcha works well (The Captcha image is shown).

Now assume that I have another area (MyArea2) and in this area, I have a controller called MyController2, then I need a new Captcha controller in this area too, otherwise, it doesn't show the image.

I cannot move CaptchaController to non area code section, as then image is not shown.

The URL to Captcha image is (for the Captcha used in view related to MyController):

```
http://mySite/MyArea/Captcha/GetImage/xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The URL to Captcha image is (for the Captcha used in view related to MyController2):

```
http://mySite/MyArea2/Captcha/GetImage/xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If I move the captcha controller to non area section, then none of the above url works and no image is shown.

If I can re route these URLs to the following URL, then they should work (I can have one Captcha controller in non area section) :

```
 http://mySite/Captcha/getImage/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your CaptchaController is not Area-specific, then it probably shouldn't be in an area.  If you relocate and renamespace it to the main Controllers directory, it should become globally accessible.

If for some reason you don't want to do that, then you can register a route with higher precedence that maps directly to your action from a global location.  The problem with the route you defined is that it does not specify the area of the controller as a parameter, but only seems to do so in the url itself.  Its a little difficult for me to debug your routing though, because (1) it isn't clear whether you are adding or removing the sample route, (2) I can't see what routes are registered before or after the sample route, (3) the ambiguity of AreaName is confusing because we can't tell if it's the area where the mapping works or doesn't work